# Can a UserControl constructor be called directly to create the control?

Tags: .net, xaml, user-controls, windows-runtime

I have a simple `UserControl`-derived control that loads correctly when included in another Xaml file. I verified that the constructor is called, which in turn calls the compiler-generated `LoadComponent()` method.

However, when I call the constructor directly to instantiate the `UserControl` programmatically, `LoadComponent()` fails with `XamlParseException`: "The text associated with this error code could not be found. Parser internal error: Object writer 'xClassNotDerivedFromElement'."

Is there any special setup that needs to occur before the constructor can be called?

Comment: I do it in my app. You'll need to include some xaml/code here, otherwise we will just be guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: this was because I was also trying to create an Application class programmatically, without Xaml. It looks like the Application class needs to be created [carefully](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242324), in particular "The Application main file must be named App.xaml."